# SQL Query that counts the number of characters match in two text columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching

I need to count how many characters are equal in two text columns (same size, in the same table). 
For example:

```
RowNum: Template:         Answers:
------- ---------         --------
   1    ABCDEABCDEABCDE   ABCDAABCDBABCDC
   2    EDAEDAEDAEDAEDA   EDBEDBEDBEDBEDB
```

SELECT SOME_COUNT_FUNCTION (Template, Answers) should return:

```
RowNum: Result:
------- -------
   1       12
   2       10
```

The database is a MySQL.

Comment: @Gorges . . . This is not a good use-case for SQL.  If you want to store multiple values like this, you should use separate rows for each character.

Comment: Actually you're right, but I received the table created (and populated) like this. Maybe should I "normalize" it with views?

Comment: . . GMB's solution is good if you are using MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly MySQL, but here's something that works in SQL Server. Maybe it'll translate over.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    [RowNum] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Template] NVARCHAR(20),
    [Answer] NVARCHAR(20),
    [Result] INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES ('ABCDEABCDEABCDE','ABCDAABCDBABCDC', NULL),
('EDAEDAEDAEDAEDA','EDBEDBEDBEDBEDB', NULL)
--SELECT * FROM #tmp

DECLARE @current_template NVARCHAR(50) -- Variable to hold the current template
,   @current_answer NVARCHAR(50) -- Variable to hold the current answer
,   @template_char CHAR(1) -- Char for template letter
,   @answer_char CHAR(1) -- Char for answer letter
,   @word_index INT -- Index (position) within each word
,   @match_counter INT -- Match counter for each word
,   @max_iter INT = (SELECT TOP 1 RowNum FROM #tmp ORDER BY RowNum DESC) -- Max iterations
,   @row_idx INT = (SELECT TOP 1 RowNum FROM #tmp) -- Minimum RowNum as initial row index value.

WHILE (@row_idx <= @max_iter)
    BEGIN
        SET @match_counter = 0 -- Reset match counter for each row
        SET @word_index = 1 -- Reset word index for each row
        SET @current_template = (SELECT [Template] FROM #tmp WHERE RowNum = @row_idx)
        SET @current_answer = (SELECT [Answer] FROM #tmp WHERE RowNum = @row_idx)
        WHILE (@word_index <= LEN(@current_template))
            BEGIN
                SET @template_char = SUBSTRING(@current_template, @word_index, 1)
                SET @answer_char = SUBSTRING(@current_answer, @word_index, 1)
                IF (@answer_char = @template_char)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @match_counter += 1
                    END
                SET @word_index += 1
            END

    UPDATE #tmp
    SET Result = @match_counter
    WHERE RowNum = @row_idx

    SET @row_idx += 1
    END
```

Get values from the temp table:

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Output:

```
RowNum  Template        Answer          Result
1       ABCDEABCDEABCDE ABCDAABCDBABCDC 12
2       EDAEDAEDAEDAEDA EDBEDBEDBEDBEDB 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query compare the strings character by character:

```
with recursive chars as (
    select rownum, template, answers, 1 idx, 0 res from mytable
    union all
    select 
        rownum, 
        template, 
        answers,
        idx + 1,
        res + ( substr(template, idx, 1) = substr(answers, idx, 1) )
    from chars
    where idx <= least(char_length(template), char_length(answers))
)
select rownum, max(res) result from chars group by rownum order by rownum
```

In the CTE (the `with` clause), the anchor (the query before `union all`) selects the whole table, then the recursive member (the query after `union all`) compares the characters and the current position (`idx`) increments the result (`res`) if they match, and advances to the next position, until the (smallest) string is exhausted. Then, the outer query just aggregates by `rownum`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17b1847955d307b532baa113ca40490b)**:

```
rownum | result
-----: | -----:
     1 |     12
     2 |     10
```

Please bear in mind that this query will not perform well against a large dataset. Other slighly more efficient solutions exist (typically, using a number table instead of a recursive cte), but basically, as commented by Gordon Linoff, you do want to *fix your data structure* if you need to run such queries. You should store each character in a separate row, along with its `rownum` and its index in the string. *Materialize* the proper data structure, and then you won't need to generate it on the fly in each and every query.